# Update of Graphics Drivers

Tags: graphics

[image]

I know that the graphics drivers are updated automatically while updating the Ubuntu Software repository.

Since I am getting an error on Eclipse and it is happening due to the old graphics(which I came to know when I googled the error).

> So I wanted to know how can I see for myself if I am using the updated graphics driver or how can I update it manually to the latest?
>   And do I also have to install any other things for the drivers to work properly?

Above is the screenshot for the additional driver section.I don't understand which one from here is better open source or the proprietary one?
I am using ubuntu 14.04(LTS).

Comment: The graphics driver is likely to be in the kernel, so every time the kernel is updated ... . If you want to know it the kernel code is updated, check the changelog or with kenrel.org.

Comment: What kind of drivers are you asking about? Proprietary or open source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to proprietary drivers and your system should run much faster.

You can try them both `fglrx` and `fglrx-updates` for this adapter.

The `updates` is newer, but for this adapter `fglrx` may be better or not.

Comment: will you please tell me what's the difference between the two?fglrx and fglrx-updates?

Comment: These are two versions of proprietary drivers. First is older, the second is newer. Try the updates. It does support your adapter. But AMD does not always well test new drivers with older adapters. Yours is not quite new, so the first may be more stable. it is hard to tell. If the updates one works OK, so keep it.

Comment: actually I have got a problem now. it's showing system is running in low graphics mode and I tried to reinstall fglrx but it didn't work

Comment: You can remove `fglrx` from console.